# Opengl shader GLSL blend two texture by coord

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

How can I blend two texture so the texture are side by side, With 50 % of texture A on the left, and 50% of texture B on the right.

for example

```
----------------
|       |      |
| 50% A | 50% B|
|       |      |
----------------
```

I want the region to be changeable, so might be 25% A 75% B.

Now I can blend two textures fully on the Rect, with each being translucent.

this is my frag shader

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D texx;
uniform float alpha;
in vec2 textureCoord;
out vec4 finalColor;

void main() {
    vec4 first_sample = texture(tex, textureCoord);
    vec4 second_sample = texture(texx, textureCoord);

    finalColor = first_sample * alpha + second_sample * (1-alpha);
}
```

Do I need to create an alpha mask texture in my C++ program?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpha mask (1D texture would be enough) is one of possible solutions, but in this particular case it isn't necessary

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform float t;    // e.g. 0.4
in vec2 texcoord;
out vec4 outColor;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 t0 = texture2D(tex0, texcoord);
    vec4 t1 = texture2D(tex1, texcoord);
    outColor = mix(t0, t1, step(t, texcoord.x));
}
```

By the way, it isn't called 'blending'. Rather 'threshold' or 'step'.

Comment: +1 for the branchless way. One could be more concise with the boolean `mix()` : `outColor = mix(t0, t1, bvec4(texcoord.x >= t));` or ternary expressions, which should translate to at least equal or even faster machine code on newer architectures : `outColor = texcoord.x < t ? t0 : t1;`

Comment: @Sam ternary is pure `if` and results in branching instructions (`cgc -profile gp5fp` - 2 more instructions, with branches). It is however possible that this would be faster in this particular case, but on other cases - i think `cgc` output is quite accurate, as it is the same compiler used within nvidia drivers internally. Need to measure actual results though... Not sure about binary mix - can't find it in standard, and cgc don't understand this one.

Comment: Not sure, which version introduces that binary mix: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/mix.xml. As far as I know, both branches of a ternary expression could be evaluated (just like both samples are taken before) and then, the mismatching one gets discarded. Benchmarking is surely the only way to find out, as there are too many different software & hardware constellations: `outColor = texcoord.x < t ? texture2D(tex0, texcoord) : texture2D(tex1, texcoord);`

Comment: Thank you. This is simpler than creating the mask texture.

Comment: Well, it was so-called 'static branching'. Dynamic branching, depending on how often condition changes, likely to be evaluated too, even if condition fails. But ternary operator and `if` is essentially the same thing (just like in C) - compiler will decide what to put here.

Comment: `- compiler will decide what to put here` that's what I'm actually counting on in the future. A ternary expression is syntactically also a bit more restricted than if & else. The compiler could translate that at least to the very same code as a binary mix would be, or perhaps, it could just swap the texture unit (what cannot be done manually, at least not when I last tried with GLSL 330). I don't want to start a debate here, your answer is backwards compatible, fast and correct.